# MySql: create table for archive engine, forcing auto_increment

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, archive, mysql-5.6

I am getting error while creating a simple table with Engine=ARCHIVE, it is forcing me to use auto_increment for primary key column, which I don't want. (Mysql 5.6).

E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE ar_my_table (
        COL_1 BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'my first column',
        ...
        PRIMARY KEY (COL_1)

) ENGINE = ARCHIVE ;
```

Above is failing with "ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error -1 from storage engine",

But if I use AUTO_INCREMENT for PK column OR don't put PK, table is created (as shown below)

```
CREATE TABLE ar_my_table (
        COL_1 BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'my first column',
        ...
        PRIMARY KEY (COL_1)

) ENGINE = ARCHIVE ;
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE ar_my_table (
        COL_1 BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'my first column',
        ...

) ENGINE = ARCHIVE ;
```

(BTW I tried creating table without PK and use ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT ... but alter statement failed with same error).

Is Auto_Increment mandatory in archive engine if I want to have PK index. Mysql reference documentation does not say anything about it (other than you can have PK and no other indices) and can have Auto_increment implying that Auto_increment is optional.

Anyone else faced same problem? Any solution to have PK without Auto_increment?

Appreciate help or guidance, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, there's nothing in MySQL docs, but I found it in MariaDB knowledge base;

> It is not a bug but a part of the limitation. The key can be a PRIMARY
>   KEY (or it can be an ordinary non-unique index), but either way it
>   must be on an AUTO_INCREMENT column.

[Q](https://lists.launchpad.net/maria-discuss/msg01742.html), [A](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/storage-engines/archive/support-for-non-auto_increment-keys/)